# ffmpeg set auto height

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I got following command which use in generate video thumbnail:

```
escapeshellcmd("/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -ss " . ceil($time) . " -i '" . $videoPath . "' -f image2 -vframes 1 -s 150x110 " . $tFilePath)
```

I want to know is that possible for the image generate in Auto Height instead of fixed Weight x Height?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with ffmpeg. Instead of `-s` you can use the [`scale`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) video filter:

```
-vf scale=150:-1
```

If the value for *w* or *h* is -1, the scale filter will use, for the respective output size, a value that maintains the aspect ratio of the input image.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it is possible via ffmpeg (but I dont think so, because I was using ffmpeg a while ago and dont remember there was something like this in api), but your goal would be to run one more ffpeg command to get informations about the file and then you can fit your height and width via php:

```
$cmd = "ffmpeg -i /var/www/web1/bates.avi 2>&1";
if(preg_match('/Video: ((\w+), (\w+), (\w+))/s', `$cmd`, $video)) {
  $video = $video[1];
  print_r($video); //flv, yuv420p, 384x204
#or
  $video = $video[4];
  print_r($video); //384x204
}
```